# How to get updated time in Java ?

Tags: java, timer

I am trying to write a simple java program which enable me to get the updated time for every seconds. All the time values are then stored in a text file. However, I am only able to get the first time and it keeps on get the same result again & again.

**Code:**

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class testTime extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Writer writer=null;
    public Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    public File file;
    protected boolean isRunning=false;

    public testTime() {
        initComponents();
        initTimer();
    }

    public void initTimer()
    {
      this.isRunning=true;  
      tryToGetUpdateTime();
    }

    public void tryToGetUpdateTime()
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        SimpleDateFormat sdfHour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat sdfMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");   

         public void run() {
            while (isRunning) {                   
                try{
                    file= new File("c:/Users/user/Desktop/updateTime.txt");

                    if(!file.exists())
                    {
                       file.createNewFile();
                    }

                    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file,true);
                    BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);                                                     bufferWritter.append("**************************************************" +  '\n');
                    bufferWritter.append(sdfMonth.format(cal.getTime()) + " " + sdfHour.format(cal.getTime()) + '\n');
                    bufferWritter.append("**************************************************" +  '\n');
                    bufferWritter.close();
                   }catch(IOException ex){
                       System.err.println("Error in Writer : " + ex);
                   }              
              }
        }
      });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new testTime().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }                  
}
```

**Output:**

```
**************************************************
15/07/2015 23:28:52
**************************************************
**************************************************
15/07/2015 23:28:52
**************************************************
**************************************************
15/07/2015 23:28:52
**************************************************
```

Comment: How do you think `Calendar` works? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `Calendar` is created, its date is not changed unless you explicitly change it, so it will always return the same value.

Secondly, it seems to me that you are instantiating the whole heavyweight `Calendar` only to take `Date` from it. There is no need for that, instantiate the `Date` directly:

```
Date date = new Date();
bufferWritter.append(sdfMonth.format(date) + " " + sdfHour.format(date) + '\n');
```

Comment: Thanks @Dragon Bozanovic, you are right! I have changed to use Date class instead. I have tried out your suggestion and it works !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing the following code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

inside tryToGetUpdateTime()

Comment: What will this accomplish?